# React says I'm trying to render an object as a React child but I can't determine where

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to render an element by mapping over a redux store, and for some reason react thinks I'm trying to return an object (error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLButtonElement]). I've looked over my entire code and several other answers to people with similar problems but nothing seems to be solving the problem.

I've followed the problem all the way back and not found a single object. I've also read several other posts on the same problem to see if the fixes there were applicable but none of the fixes for other people worked in this code. I'm pretty new at this so I could be missing something obvious but I've been at this for a few hours and haven't made any meaningful headway.

The code that is causing the problem is the onClick within the li tag in this block.

```
 <ul id = 'currentTasks'>
      {this.props.tasks.map( (task, idx) => {
           return (
                <li onClick = {this.completeHandler(event.target)} key={idx}>{task}</li>
                     )
            })
      }
</ul>
```

The handler it's referencing is just

```
completeHandler(target) {
     this.props.completeTask(target)
```

Which references this block in my redux store

```
const compTask = (task) => {
    return {
        type: COMP,
        task
    }
}
```

Also I don't know if the problem is here but here is my two piece of mapToProps code, I've seen problems where the error was there

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        tasks: state[0],
        compTasks: state[1]
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        submitNewTask: (nTask) => {
            dispatch(addTask(nTask))
        },
        completeTask: (cTask) => {
            dispatch(compTask(cTask))
        }
    }
};
```

and here is my redux store, just in case the problem is in how I'm storing tasks

```
const taskReducer = (state = [[],[]], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD: 
            return [state[0].concat(action.task), [...state[1]]];
        case COMP:
            let idx = state[0].indexOf(action.task);
            let beg = state.slice(0, idx);
            let end = state.slice(idx + 1);
            let newState = [[...beg, ...end], [...state[1], action.task]];
            return newState;
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

The whole app is live at https://jeengland.github.io/molehills/ in case you wanted to see the problem and error live.

Sorry if I've put too much I just have no idea where the problem could be happening. The react error is woefully unspecific so I don't know what could be causing it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**edit:** I successfully solved the problem with the advice from the two below comments, and also the realization I was using event.target when I should have been using event.target.innerHTML. More details in the comments.

Comment: Turns out that all my problems were rooted in my use of event.target, which not only was in the wrong place but was the wrong code. I was trying to target the _inside_ of the list element, but was using event target which literally passed "<li>" into the function instead of the value within <li></li>. The correct expression to use was event.target.innerHTML, which successfully pulled the list value out of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems while reviewing the code.

1) Invoking the event handler instead of passing a function:

```
<li onClick = {this.completeHandler(event.target)}
```

2) event.target is undefined. Instead, pass the task

```
<li onClick = {this.completeHandler.bind(this, task)}
```

3) task might be an object (event object) which is giving the error. Use something like task name within the li tag

```
<li onClick = {this.completeHandler(event.target)} key={idx}>{task.name}</li>
```

4) Instead of doing mapDispatchToProps, you can use the object version, sort of easier shortcut when params match.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  submitNewTask: addTask,
  completeTask: compTask
}
```

Comment: Ok, following your advice I have managed to make it one step further before things break. Getting a similar error as before, but will try to apply this advice across all of my new problems. One thing I did run into was when I tried to implement your advice # 2 and change it to this.completeHandler(this, task), it kept telling me task was undefined. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick

```
onClick = {this.completeHandler(event.target)}
```

You are invoking `this.completeHandler` by having the `()`.

Change it to:

```
onClick = {this.completeHandler.bind(this)}
```

And change the function argument to `event`

```
completeHandler(event) {
     this.props.completeTask(event.target)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice! I already had an argument set up to define this.completeHandler as this.completeHandler.bind(this) but I didn't realize I was calling it incorrectly.